# Custom Step of shared library causes java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Our declarative pipeline(for isolating the problem) is using a custom step of our shared library. This custom step shall represent a long running operation by just calling Thread.sleep (360000).

Code:

```
pipeline
{
    agent
    {
        label'master'
    }
    options
    { 
        timestamps() 
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        skipDefaultCheckout()
    }

    stages
    { 
        stage('Thread.sleep')
        {

            steps{
                sleepService(360000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom step from shared library:

```
import java.lang.*;

def String call(long millis) {

    timeout(600)
    {
        echo "Current thread name: ${Thread.currentThread().getName()}"
        echo "Current thread classname: ${Thread.currentThread().getClass().getName()}"
        Thread.sleep (millis)
    }
}
```

Executing this, is causing the following exception:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java_lang_Thread$sleep.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at soiServiceSleep.call(soiServiceSleep.groovy:9)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor577.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:281)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems like this is caused by timeout of 5 minutes of the CPSThread.

How can we overcome this problem?

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Have you tried using `sleep(time: millis, unit: "MILLISECONDS")` workflow step (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#sleep-sleep)? I don't know if your Jenkins infrastructure uses nodes to delegate pipeline execution, but if you call `Thread.sleep()`, you essentially block a thread on a master node. (Every Java/Groovy code in Jenkinsfile or Jenkins Shared Library gets executed on the master node.) Workflow step will run sleep on the Jenkins node that executes the pipeline.

Comment: Thread.sleep is just standing as a placeholder of a long running operation somewhere in a stack of Java method calls. Therefore it is not replaceable with the sleep step.

Comment: You can't use `Thread.sleep` in pipeline, as it is blocking the same thread that is responsible for measuring the timeout on the whole operation. If you're not actually using `Thread.sleep` then post whatever it is  you're using.

Comment: We are using in our custom steps a webservice client to control our VMware infrastructure and internally it is using Thread.sleep. I cannot influence that.